# How to change color of heatmap plot in heatmaply using dropdown menu in R?

Tags: r, plotly, heatmaply

I would like to change color of heatmap plot in heatmaply using dropdown menu in R.
I wrote below code but doesn't work properly. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
 df<- 
 structure(c(5.91907, 3.05747, 5.73896, 5.30454, 4.74619, 6.60657, 
 5.81497, -12.425, 1.93861, 5.16512, 5.93555, 2.78618, 5.67026, 
 5.2143, 4.76254, 6.61845, 5.88446, -12.425, 1.80812, 5.21011, 
 5.95742, 2.67871, 5.62981, 5.29438, 4.81968, 6.65069, 5.91714, 
-12.425, 1.88218, 5.18672, 7.47528, 10.18474, 7.36668, 3.29509, 
 6.09987, 5.10079, 6.48144, 3.0804, 0.00595, 5.7687, 7.49799, 
 10.44368, 7.29894, 3.28727, 6.12365, 5.20986, 6.51248, 1.88641, 
 -0.13119, 5.69689, 7.53807, 10.44435, 7.32447, 3.31082, 6.15386, 
 5.11612, 6.49, 3.01725, 0.19859, 5.76166), .Dim = c(10L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
 c("Rrp9", "Prm1", "Gprc5a", "Fzd2", "Aen", "Cdkn2c", "Eps8", 
 "Mir6924", "Lpin1", "E2f8"), c("A", "B", 
 "C", "D", "E", "F"
  )))
library(magrittr)
library(heatmaply)
library(gplots)

clus <- hclust(dist(df))
d <- df[clus$order,]

 heatmaply(d , na.rm = TRUE, showticklabels =c (TRUE,FALSE) , k_col = 4, 
 k_row = 5, col=greenred(10),
  main = "HeatMap for all DE genes across all sets") %>%
 layout( updatemenus = list(
list(
 y = 0.8,
 buttons = list(
 list(method = "update",
     args = list("colors", "greenred(10)"),
     label = "GreenRed"),

list(method = "update",
     args = list("colors", "bluered(10)"),
     label = "BlueRed")))
  )) %>%  config(displayModeBar = TRUE , modeBarButtons= FALSE,setBackground= "transparent")
```

Comment: Your code does not work.  Does not produce anything. Include all libraries needed to run your code.

Comment: The code works just needs three libraries. I added them.

Comment: The update arguments cannot be R code (`bluered(10)`), since they will be interpreted with a HTML page and not in an R session. The binding to colour happens before the plot is rendered to HTML/JS so I don't think this is possible